# What is this floating obelisk thing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

What is this thing? Is it dangerous? Is it useful?

[image]

I've scoured the [Technic Pack Wiki](http://technicpack.wikia.com) and I'm stumped. I don't even know which of the pack's mods this thing comes from. The page on [obelisks](http://technicpack.wikia.com/wiki/Obelisks) I *did* find appears to be an entirely different structure. This thing I'm looking at is not a Mystcraft obelisk – they aren't connected to the ground, and in any case I've found them in my overworld too. They're definitely from some other mod in the pack.

I haven't had the courage to mess with them yet (apart from walking around under it and learning that I don't immediately explode or turn into a zombie), but I've just found a Mystcraft world where there are a half-dozen right around the spawn – if I can exploit them somehow I've hit the motherlode.

Comment: A downvote already! Do I have food on my face? Is the title too cheeky? Either of those can be fixed if I knew what the objection was.

Comment: I didn't downvote but the title is really bad.

Comment: @dbemerlin Fair enough. It's honestly what I first thought when I found my first one.

Comment: do not lick the floating obelisk!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://technicpack.wikia.com/wiki/Eldritch_Monolith

> Obelisks found in forest, plains, mountain and jungle biomes are
>   surrounded by a small floor made out of various types of stone bricks
>   and up to four pillars made out of circular stone bricks. Obelisks in
>   desert biomes are surrounded by sandstone instead, and have up to four
>   pillars made out of various types of ornamental sandstone. In swamp
>   biomes, the floor and the pillars surrounding the Obelisks are made
>   from mossy cobblestone.
>
> Below the obelisk is a shaft made out of unbreakable Eldritch Stones
>   which reaches to the very bottom of the map. Those eldritch stones
>   themselves are seemingly indestructible and resist even the most
>   sturdy of diamond pickaxes

TL;DR: They are markers for secret chambers full of treasure far below them.

Comment: Sweet! Then this world really is the motherlode. I really wish the wiki was more discoverable.

Comment: Be careful digging under it, though, as the shafts don't exist until the obelisk is unlocked.

Comment: @SaintWacko I just read that. And trying random unlocks makes it blow up! Technic adds so many exciting ways to die.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - The creators probably play Dwarf Fortress. **Losing is Fun!**

Comment: Once you unlock one, you CAN mine the stones (Eldritch Stones), provided that you have good tools. If you have some of the advanced tools from IC2, they work - specifically, the Diamond Drill and the Mining Laser (set to long-range, it will destroy one Eldritch Stone). If you are trying to unlock it, it's easiest if you craft the Goggles of Revealing so you can see the combination.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You need goggles of unvealing and crystals to unlock the obelisk.